# Stop only one docker container via dokku

Tags: docker, dokku, dokku-alt

I have `dokku v0.11.3` and I use DOKKU_SCALE to scale my containers.
I want to stop only one docker container. How can I do this?
I thought that it's possible via `dokku ps:scale app_name proc_name=0`
but it doesn't work in my situation. Dokku always scales containers according to DOKKU_SCALE file when I use this command.

Is it possible to stop only one container if I use DOKKU_SCALE file?

Right now, I can do this only via `docker stop`

Comment: You want to stop a specific container or just scale down by 1?

Comment: @TarunLalwani stop specific container

Comment: @TarunLalwani in my case, I have only one such container, so scale down by 1 could work for me too. Is it possible?

Comment: Looking at their code, it seems like it should work when you provide the proc=scale. https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/f115815ced09b74a3dc9e84facf05f416c38ba76/plugins/ps/functions#L153